# Testing the accuracy of a created Index

Tags: portfolio-management, index, statistical-finance, performance-evaluation

So long story short, I created a Oil/Energy Index from a basket of 5 stocks in the asset class.

I am looking to use mean-reversion, in order to help rebalance the allocation of funds between difference asset classes. As a result, I had to create my own index, as the package I'm using doesn't have enough historical data on ETFs.

I have created the Index, using Laspeyres as shown [here](https://www.nyse.com/publicdocs/nyse/indices/nyse_sector_index_methodology.pdf) . I'm wondering what would be a good statistical method of testing how accurate this etf is against the performance of the stocks.

I was thinking a PCA, but wasn't sure what this community thought.

Comment: Please don't remove posts, regardless of whether you get an answer.

Comment: A warm welcome to Quant.SE and thank you for that interesting question. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @BobJansen Will keep that in mind, sorry about that... didn't want to spam the board

Comment: No problem, welcome to Quant.SE!

Comment: @vonjd So i read the paper you linked, but my question is how would I measure the accuracy of the index, against the basket of stocks I used to create it. The paper linked relates the accuracy of ETFs, relative to the Index. Aside from the fact that a general Index like SPY doesn't have enough data, I don't think it's what I'm looking for

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Measuring the accuracy of an index against a basket of stocks seems to me equivalent to an ETF. An ETF basically *is* a basket of of stocks. Please clarify. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want to assess is the tracking error or tracking efficiency. A good place to start is the following report from Morningstar:

[On The Right Track:
Measuring Tracking Efficiency in ETFs](http://media.morningstar.com/uk/MEDIA/Research_Paper/Morningstar_Report_Measuring_Tracking_Efficiency_in_ETFs_February_2013.pdf)

In the report are numerous calculation methodologies (and they give their own on top of that).

I wouldn't say that PCA is a natural choice because of its limited interpretability in this context.

Comment: thank you for the direction, will look into it today. Also, would you recommend something other than Laspeyres for the Index... something geometric-based as discussed here: https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/wp/2012/wp12105.pdf